Position of Subjektsprädikativ after "desto"
An adjective/adverb follows "desto": Desto besser.
What if I have a phrase like "verbunden sein" or "vertraut sein", where can I put the adjective?
Can I put it directly behind the comparison?

Je mehr man sich kennenlernt, desto besser vertraut ist man miteinander.
Je mehr man lernt, desto hervorragender gebildet kann man wirken.

Or:

Je mehr man sich kennenlernt, desto besser ist man miteinander vertraut.


All of these examples are grammatical. I find "hervorragender gebildet" a somewhat weird phrase (with or without "desto"); usually you would say just "gebildeter", but they are still all grammatical.

And we also do not say "mehr kennenlernen" but "näher kennenlernen".
